# Proteger arquivo de configuração secreto

Tags: php, arquivo, segurança

Eu tenho um arquivo isolado dos outros chamado `config.php`. Ele guarda informações de 3 *databases* e algumas senhas sigilosas, mas necessárias para o funcionamento do sistema como um todo. Eu queria proteger esse arquivo de alguma forma, qualquer um que acesse meu servidor e o encontre vai poder ler as informações nele contidas e atrapalhar meu sistema depois. Existe alguma solução para isso?

Comment: Vcoê quer proteger essa informação que de que tipo de acesso, apenas requisições?

Comment: E essa? Dá para aceitar alguma?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Se essas senhas são necessárias para o funcionamento do sistema, então elas têm de estar disponíveis em formato original (ou equivalente) a esse sistema, seja em disco seja em memória. 100% de proteção, portanto, é impossível, mas você pode tomar algumas medidas para limitar o seu acesso.

Em primeiro lugar, faça uma lista de quem você **confia** e quem você não confia:

- Quem possui acesso físico ao servidor, quem possui a senha de root, e quem acessa a conta que é dona (*owner*) desse arquivo de configurações, nesses você precisa confiar - não há nada que você possa fazer para impossibilitar o acesso destes ao arquivo;
- Se você não confia nos demais usuários do servidor, proteger o arquivo com `chmod` é um meio de limitar seu acesso (isso é algo bom de ser feito de qualquer forma). Sugiro `600` - o dono pode ler e escrever, o grupo e os demais não podem fazer nada.
- Se você confia nos operadores, mas quer evitar seu acesso *acidental* aos dados (ex.: eles abriram pra resolver um problema, e acabaram vendo a senha), convém codificá-los de alguma forma, por exemplo em base64.
- Em todos os casos, mantenha esse arquivo inacessível via internet - seja fora da raiz do seu *website*/aplicação, seja protegido com controles de acesso (ex.: `.htaccess`).

Por fim, uma opção pros casos mais "paranóicos" (pode ser necessário em caso de dados extremamente confidenciais, mas na maioria das vezes é exagero) é criptografar esses dados sigilosos, exigindo uma senha para sua descriptografia. Assim, ao dar o *boot* no sistema, o operador entraria com essa senha, que decifraria os demais dados e os guardariam em memória somente - e de preferência em uma região de memória que não sofre *swap*. A desvantagem óbvia dessa abordagem é que se o servidor precisar ser reiniciado a senha terá de ser fornecida novamente - provocando perda de disponibilidade caso o operador autorizado não esteja presente.

Um meio termo seria usar um módulo de hardware para fazer essa descriptografia, de modo que os requisitos de confiança se resumem a quem tem acesso físico à máquina (i.e. nem o *root* poderia decifrar os dados sigilosos). Resta entretanto a possibilidade do usuário *root* usar um processo para ler a memória de outro, mas não sei dizer o quão viável/provável é esse cenário.

Answer (score 5):

Não há muito o que fazer. Você pode proteger do acesso externo com os meios tradicionais e proteger todo o servidor para que não tenha acesso indevido mas alguém estando no servidor fica complicado proteger esta informação.

Alguns dirão para criptografar o arquivo ou pelo menos os dados sensíveis. Mas com acesso ao servidor o dado descriptografado ou a forma de descriptografar está disponível também.

Se a intenção é proteger de acesso externo pode colocar o arquivo fora da área do *website* em um diretório separado provavelmente em uma hierarquia abaixo. Isto fará o suficiente.

Se seu *website* está em `/http/public`, pode colocar em `/http`.

Se não puder fazer isto, pode configurar o `.htaccess` com:

```
<files config.php>
order allow,deny
deny from all
</files>
```

Outra forma óbvia é limitar o acesso com permissões `chmod`. Nunca coloque 777, provavelmente um 400 será suficiente. Mas isto por si só não basta.

Answer (score 3):

Uma das maneiras que você pode utilizar para bloquear o acesso a esse arquivo seria por meio de uma regra via arquivo `.htaccess`, especificando o arquivo na diretiva [`<Files>`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#files):

```
<Files "config.php">
  Order Allow,Deny
  Deny from all
</Files>
```

Se for necessário fazer o mesmo com outros arquivos, você pode usar a diretiva [`<FilesMatch>`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#filesmatch), ela faz a mesma coisa que `<Files>`, mas aceita expressões regulares.

```
<FilesMatch "config\.php|function\.php|include\.php">
  Order allow,deny
  Deny from all
</FilesMatch>
```